# XSL-FO no text-indent at the top of a new page

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

Is it possible to prevent a text-indent variable at the top of a new page of a document?

Code:

```
<xsl:template match="paragraph">
  <fo:block text-indent="10pt">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

New page:

xxxxxxx

instead of:

text-indent xxxxxxx

To avoid a text-indent at the first paragraph of a chapter i used the code below, but this won't help me with the text-indent at a new page:

```
<xsl:template match="paragraph">
   <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="fn:position() = 1">
           <fo:block>
             <xsl:value-of select="."/>
           </fo:block>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
          <fo:block text-indent="10pt">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </fo:block>
       </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What FO processor are you working with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not possible to determine the presence and position of page breaks before the actual FO processing has taken place.<sup>1</sup>

The reason is the following. In XSL-FO, you are not modelling pages. Rather, you define *flows* and *regions* wherein text is allowed to "flow". It is left to the FO processor to sort out how content is divided into pages.

A consequence of this is that certain kinds of information are not available beforehand, like the `Is there going to be a page-break?` info you are looking for or, prominently, the [number of pages](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/fo.html#fo-total-pages).

On the other hand, you can easily control when a page break should always be inserted of course. If you specify [page-break-after](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#page-break-after) or [page-break-before](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#page-break-before) on `fo:block` elements, you can at least make sure that the first paragraph of each chapter starts on a new page.

```
<fo:block page-break-before="always">Chapter title</fo:block>
```

That way, as a small consolation, the indentation of the first paragraph on a new page is omitted if it coincides with a new chapter.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that we are talking about page breaks that are *automatically* introduced by `FOP` without the intervention of a user.

Comment: I am using this code for page-break:
  `<xsl:apply-templates select="paragraph"/>
  <xsl:if test="fn:not(fn:position() = fn:last())"><fo:block page-break-before="always"/></xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>`
This works fine and there is no page-break afer the last chapter, but i still have the problem, that paragraphs on the top of a new page do have a text-indent, which ist pretty annoying.

Comment: "The reason is the following. In XSL-FO, you are not modelling pages. Rather, you define flows and regions wherein text is allowed to "flow". It is left to the FO processor to sort out how content is divided into pages."

I see the problem. But still, XSL-Fo is used to create a book-layout, so there has to be a way, to prevent the text-indent at the top of a new page.

Comment: I have been looking for those features quite a while now myself, but could not find them. Perhaps you can get help here: http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/maillist.html.

Comment: By the way, do you specify `keep-together.within-page` on the paragraph blocks?

Comment: Wow! `keep-with-next.within-page="always"` actually works! Thank you! As a result, every page begins with a paragraph of the previous page, so there is no indentation.